# Laravel using inRandomOrder how to prevent duplicate record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm Using Laravel 10 I'm trying to get Random Record Without Duplication  using inRandomOrder But It Giving Duplicate Record Some Time.
help me to Solve It

My Controller Code

```
$Question = Question::inRandomOrder()->limit(50)->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get random records without duplication using Laravel's `inRandomOrder()` method, you can use `distinct()` method to get unique records

```
$questions = Question::inRandomOrder()
->limit(50)
->distinct()
->get();
```

Comment: if I use $questions = Question::inRandomOrder()
->limit(50)
->distinct()
->get()->shuffle();   it make any sense

Comment: @user12931578 try to do this experiment & also do some debug & you will get your desired results!!